# WebView Cocos2d xna

Tags: webview, xna, cocos2d-iphone

I want to display a web page in the background of my game using Cocos2D XNA for windows phone 7. I was found many examples that how it will be created on iOS, but nothing about XNA

Let me know the possible ways.
Excuse my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, you have to render the web page into a texture2d and then display the texture2d as a CCSprite. This is no easy task in XNA.